# VBA to Open Excel File and Paste Sheet 1 Data into "RRimport" Sheet in Current Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Ok so I have a current workbook (Original Workbook) with several Sheets. I would like to open an existing workbook (Data Workbook) and copy all of the contents in Sheet 1 of 'Data Workbook', then paste everything into Sheet "RRimport" of 'Original Workbook'. At the end of this process I would like to close the 'Data Workbook' So far I have the following code, however it currently pastes a **new sheet** right after my sheet names "ARGimport" of my Original Workbook:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        If Sheet.Visible = True Then
            Sheet.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets("ARGimport")
        End If
    Next Sheet

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Thanks to the help of [rdhs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2146688/rdhs) I was able to figure this out. Updated and working code below:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [RRimport!A1]

Sheets("RRimport").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [RRimport!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
FileFilter:="Report Files *.xls (*.xls),")

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

    For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        With Sheet.UsedRange
            .Copy PasteStart
            Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End With
    Next Sheet

End If

    wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it's almost there! It pastes into the specified sheet (RRimport) now, however, I need it to delete the old content on that sheet and paste only the new data. As of now if the old content had stuff going until row 999, and the new data only has 500 rows worth of data, rows 501-999 are still there. I need it to delete the old data and have only the new data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was actually able to figure out the rest. I've updated the code above. Thanks rdhs!