# Convert multiple tsv files to a single csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

Good Morning Everyone

I am very new to this and a little out of my depth. I was wondering if it was possible in PowerShell to do a couple of things (or if not PowerShell what else might do this).

We will receive a number of emails a day with 1 or more (up to a max of 7 I believe) TSV files attached.  An outlook extension process is stripping these attachments and dropping them into a folder called “tsv files to be processed”.  Each file already has a unique filename so there is no issue of files overwriting each other.

In case it matters I should mention that the TSV file contains numbers with the thousands separated by a comma (4,000).

These TSV files all need merging into a single csv file which at the end of the day is sent to another directory which we have called “output csv file” with a fixed filename so that it can be imported.

After processing, the TSV files should be shunted to an archive directory so they are not processed more than once. For this, we created the folder “archive tsv files”.

Within the “output csv file” directory we will process the file once a day so ideally we would like to move this file at say 12:30 to another directory we called “output csv files archive” (as you can see we spent a lot of time on folder naming).  At this point, we would add the date to the filename outputcsv so that it becomes outputcsv280916 (for today) or incrementally if this is easier (e.g. outputcsv1, outputcsv2 etc).

If this is a real newbie question please be patient as I'm really new at this.

Many Thanks

Paul

Comment: There are a lot of separate questions in this... I think you need to break it down in to the individual parts, go away and put something together by looking through previous questions and online tutorials, and then come back if there is a specific thing you are stuck on. As a start, I would look in to 'VBA opening tsv files', then 'moving contents of tsv file to new workbook' and finally 'saving workbook as csv file in vba'. The rest are little things you can work out from there

Comment: Thanks for the response Gallus, i'll try this although doing a quick search on "VBA opening tsv files" returned nothing, I tried several variants of the question and got nothing except connection via ODBC Q's and A's.

Comment: This is sort of the line you need to go down for step 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966526/vba-to-open-excel-file-and-paste-sheet-1-data-into-rrimport-sheet-in-current-w it's then all about joining the bits of script together into one sub, to open each file in the folder and copy the contents over to a new workbook, then save that workbook. Once you have a script put together, come back if you have issues in it and people will be able to help improve it. We can't write a script from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use Import-Csv and Export-Csv.

```
if (Test-Path 'out.csv') { del 'out.csv' }
dir '*.tsv' | ForEach {
    Import-Csv $_ -Delimiter "`t" | Export-Csv 'out.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
    move $_ 'archive tsv files'
}
```

If the files are big this will be slower than reading them directly as text and replacing tab character but that's another question.

Comment: Good Morning, with a lot of help from people that was all done in about 40 lines of code and I have started looking with Ernest at a PowerShell scripting course.